# What would Shazam’s wand have done with Sivana?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, shazam-2019

In Shazam (2019) if Sivana’s plan had succeeded and he had gotten

> Billy to hold the wand of power and Sivana said “Shazam”

What would have happened?

> A) would Billy have lost the Shazam power as it transferred to Sivana (just as it had transferred from the wizard to Billy)

Or

> B) or would Sivana be an additional Shazam and Billy would have kept his powers (just like it did with the siblings later on)

?

Comment: Ummm, ***magic***?

Comment: Billy hasn’t been taught any magic except that one word.

Comment: The core question is whether Sivana would have taken the power away or if there would be two Shazam’s.

Comment: @RoboKaren Then ask that specifically, because right now, no, that isn't the core question.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist thanks. Clarified the question.

Comment: Did the wizard actually lose his powers? That's the implication of the dialog, but I don't actually remember evidence one way or the other.